# Aptana crashes on windows 7 until .metadata folder is deleted

Tags: windows-7, aptana

I have used Eclipse and Apatana for years on Linux, but have recently switched to Windows 7 in order to be compatible with my business partners.  I have installed the 'Aptana Studio 3.4.0 Microsoft Windows, x86' standalone version of Aptana, and after install it runs great until I close it.  When I try to re-open it, it hangs ('not responding' message) and I have not found any way to resolve the issue other than deleting the .metadata directory in my aptana workspace, which of course deletes all my project references, deployment settings, and any other tweaks I've made to the app, and setting this back up every time I restart the app is a waste of my time.  Can anyone identify the problem?  I have a pastebin of my log at:

http://pastebin.com/2J0AWTNR

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Did you fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

instead of deleting the whole `.metadata`, you can try to delete the `.markers` file for any open project:

in this folder:

```
...\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\[myProject]
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete (if it exists), then add an empty `.metadata` folder inside your project directory.

I had the same problem on Windows 7, Aptana hanging for eternity on startup.
Following posts like this one I looked for the `.metadata` folder inside the project directory but didn't see any there.
I tried creating an empty `.metadata` folder in the project directory, and Aptana started up.

Answer (score 0):

Have had the same problem and I've reinstalled which makes no difference. So I deleted the .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects folder and it fixed it and with no settings/data etc loss amazingly :-)

Answer (score 0):

I used this fix at first and then ran into more problems after a while. The sidebars and other objects in the program were not working and as a result the program just stopped responding. I have finally found a fix here http://youtu.be/RYobTLq_hms?list=UUtL_0WLPWmHZE_HcX48F96w and I hope that this helps for all! We can finally get back to work!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call the following a fix, but it helped me so here it goes:

My Aptana didn't start. It would just hang and when you click anywhere in the blank screen Windows would say the program isn't responding...

This is what "fixed" it for me:

1. Navigate to: C:\Users\YOURNAME\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\
2. Create a new dir and move the ".metadata" dir into it.
3. Start Aptana

Aptana will run now, but all your projects will be gone.

4. Remove the new ".metadata" directory that Aptana just created at startup.
5. Move the ".metadata" folder out of the one you just created, back to its
   original location.
6. Now run Aptana again.

This fixed my problem.